# Проблема синхронизации карты в мультиплере Photon, Unity

Tags: unity3d, synchronized

Делаю простую мультиплеерную игру,используя Photon. Игрок двигается и за ним ломаются блоки.Простое движение работает нормально и на обоих клиентах все разрушенные/неразрушенные плитки отображаются одинаково.

Я добавил рывок. Во время рывка на игроке должен отключаться box collider, соответственно плитки под не должны ломаться пока рывок не окончен. Добавляю фото. Слева мастер-клиент создавший комнату, у него рывок работает правильно и есть 2 неразрушенные плитки. Но на втором клиенте все блоки разрушились, хотя рывок тоже был совершен.

Каким образом можно синхронизировать изменения карты между двумя игроками? Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно либо синхронизировать состояние `box collider`, либо сделать так, что за состояние карты будет отвечать один (мастер) клиент, а второй клиент будет менять состояние карты только по команде от мастера.

Comment: А каким образом можно синхронизировать box collider?

Comment: Я знаю что вроде бы можно как то через OnPhotonSerializeView, и там либо SendNext, если отправляешь, либо ReceiveNext. Но там можно передавать только массив байтов, а boxcollider не получится

Comment: Вам нужно не целиком boxCollider синхронизировать, а только включен он или выключен (поле enabled).

Comment: Для надежности стоит сделать так, что блоки может фактически уничтожать только мастер клиент. Что-то вроде. 
Отправка события об уничтожении блока

int blockNumber = 3;
var reo = new RaiseEventOptions {Receivers = ReceiverGroup.All};
var so = new SendOptions {Reliability = true};
PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent(69, blockNumber, reo, so);

И фактическое уничтожение блока 

public void OnEvent(EventData event)
{
   if (event.Code == 69)
        BlockDest((int) event.CustomData);
}

Подробнее https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent#raiseevent

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вот этим способом если реализовывать, то только игрок1, являющийся мастер клиентом, может ломать блоки? А другой игрок?

Comment: Тут есть варианты: 
другой игрок может отправлять запросы типа "хочу сломать блок", но решение о том будет ли сломан блок принимает мастер клиент
ЛИБО
мастер клиент ведь и так все знает о другом игроке? Вот пусть и ломает блоки. 
В методе поломки блока: `if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return; SendBlockDestroyEvent();`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: с помощью аттрибута [PunRPC] вызывать методы для удаления этих блоков, но смотри не запутайся с вызовами этих методов